# Nagios check giving error and not the output I expect

Tags: python, pandas, nagios

I have a python code which when run locally gives correct output but when I run it with Nagios check locally it gives errors.

Code :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("...")
print(df)
```

Nagios configuration :

1. inside localhost.cfg

```
define service {
       use                 local-service
       host_name           localhost
       service_description active edges
       check_command.      check_edges
}
```

2. inside commands.cfg

```
define command {
    command_name  check_edges
    command_line  $USER1$/check_edges.py $HOSTADDRESS$ 
}
```

Error :

```
(No output on stdout) stderr : Traceback File "/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_edges.py" line 3, in <module> import pandas as pd
ImportError: No module named pandas
```

Please give as much details as possible to solve this problem

****pip show python gives :
Location: /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload

pip show pandas gives :
Location : /home/nwvepops01/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages****

Comment: First, you have `.` inside service definition, which is bad. Next, error msg is self-explanation - you do not have Python module `pandas` or is not installed for user running your Nagios instance.

Comment: @Rohlik I have pandas installed but they are in different location. do they have to be in same location?

Comment: @Rohlik pip show python gives : Location: /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload

pip show pandas gives : Location : /home/nwvepops01/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages

Comment: @Rohlik how do you check if pandas is installed for nagiosadmin user?

Comment: What if you switch to your Nagios user and try run your script? Is it work?

Comment: I uninstalled pandas, re installed it under /usr/local/bin.
I used option 2 where I modified .bashrc - last line with correct path as /usr/local/bin. when I do echo $PYTHONPATH I get /usr/local/bin. I have used chown to give Nagios:nagios as permission to all files being used with this plugin.

Comment: I also did this just now,
I created a small python script under /usr/local/bin called mod.py
#!/usr/bin/env python
s = "hbchjbchjfe"
then under check_edges.py , where I was importing pandas earlier I wrote :
form mod import s
print(s) 
I ran this locally from check_edges.py and it ran fine and gave me o/p of s value.
Nagios does not give me s o/p on GUI. but it says "no module named mod" now.

Comment: Maybe it help try use something like `command_line  /bin/env PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/bin  $USER1$/check_edges.py $HOSTADDRESS$ `. Or maybe `/usr/lib/python2.7/lib`? Can you try it?

Comment: thank you for the help. python script was not in the right location where I had installed my packages. it works now.

Answer (score 0):

As user, from the shell, check the istance of python.
For example with this command:

```
env python
```

Modify the script and on the first line replace this

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

with the absolute path of the python executable.

Comment: env python : Python 2.7.17 (default, Apr ...) [GCC 7.5.0] on linux2. I can run the python script locally from  my machine but not with Nagios tool. I have 1st line on python as : #!/usr/bin/env python

Comment: which is the full path of python 2.7.17 ?

Comment: when I do print(sys.executable) I get /usr/bin/python

Comment: Good. follow my answer!